# how to do OTA programming on CC2538 SoC?

Tags: embedded

I am trying over-the-air (OTA) programming on CC2538 SOC.

Initially I started Z-stack in IAR Embedded Workbench, getting many errors I couldn't resolve.

Now I am trying on Linux platform.

Can any one suggest me any web pages or any tutorials to implement this task?

Comment: That is not how SO works. Here you ask your question, and get answers. You should not ask for a link to a resource that might answer your question. If you get _build_ errors, post the build log and code and you will get answers. If these are runtime errors, describe them and add the associated code that is failing.  I am not sure how you think changing development host will help.

Comment: Follow [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjX546K9ZHoAhUCAGMBHWgPBNEQFjABegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fe2echina.ti.com%2Fcfs-file%2F__key%2Fcommunityserver-discussions-components-files%2F104%2FZ_2D00_Stack-OTA-Upgrade-User_2700_s-Guide.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0slyXtAYDlV7q4XDByvZjs) and explain where you run into problems.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Gerhard. while Building the Initial Sample Applications for CC2538 it generates these errors ..              
   Error[Li005]: no definition for "macBackoffTimerRolloverCallback" [referenced from C:\Texas Instruments\Z-Stack 3.0.0\Projects\zstack\HomeAutomation\

Comment: Different Z-Stack versions uses different IAR versions. Use the IAR version that is described in release note. What version are you using?

Comment: Add the errors to your question with the edit option.